# Erlang in Windows - Process Increase?

Tags: memory, process, erlang

I am using Erlang and have just got started with it. I keep hitting a process_limit in Windows and can't figure out how to increase the process limit ?

I am using `WERL.exe` and would appreciate the commands to increase this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your windows `cmd prompt`, you can fire up an erlang shell by typing `erl` on the terminal prompt and hitting `Enter`. However, this will only work if, you have the `erl.exe` full path in your windows `$PATH` environment variable. This should be the folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\erl5.8.5\bin` on my machine, for the latest Erlang. I am sure you can find a way to add this to your environment PATH variable, close all terminals and open again and try entering the `erl` command. 
Now, this should happen:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\machine> erl
Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

Now, to increase the possible number of processes, you add a [Flag](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) like this:
 `erl +P [Maximum No. of Processes]` e.g. If i want to be able to spawn 13421779 processes within the erlang instance then i can issue the command like this

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\machine> erl +P 13421779
Eshell V5.8.4  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

However, still, as you will realize later, even this maximum number has an upper limit. :)